# When using hydrate, why do we need to match the classNames in both server and client, and How?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React 16 & Hydrate. My server.js uses StaticRouter and my client uses BrowserRouter. I am using Material-UI.

I constantly get class mismatch warning.

Why is this warning? 
What is the significance of this warning?
Is it a security risk or just best practice?
How do I stop getting this warning?

I know, we should have only one specific question to be asked, but if some could guide me to some really good  documentation page, which will answer all these questions.
please help....

Comment: Can you provide a code sandbox on https://codesandbox.io? So we can diagnose the problem and find a solution to stop getting the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material UI generates a different class for each component after rendering. It is literally not possible to predict what the end class name will be. While you're on localhost the class could be **.newLoanStepper-root-247** but once you build the app the class name would change to something like **.jss01026**

You will need to follow the MUI guide for server rendering if you want to use the library https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/

Comment: Thanks a lot, This was a page I skipped.... sorry. I will have a read and come back. But for now this is a better answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Avinash no problem, material ui is a bit messy in terms of classname generation  anyways